# Enable and Disable Sorting of JTable dynamically

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, rowsorter

I'm new to Java Swing and I'm working with JTable.

Actually, I have difficulty in sorting of this component.

I want to enable and disable this function programatically.

I use `JTable.setAutoCreateSorter(true)` to initialize it, I change to false, nothing happen.

Also, I had use `JTable.setRowSorter(null)`, it works, but I do not know how to enable it again.

Sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setSortable(int index, boolean sortable)` method of DefaultRowSorter.

```
    for (int i=0 ; i<table.getColumnCount() ; i++) {
        sorter.setSortable(i, false);
    }
```

This worked for me. See also [JTable sorting programatically only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978489/jtable-sorting-programatically-only/19997022#19997022)

Comment: Thanks Macias. It offers me great help as I expected!

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting at [JTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(boolean autoCreateRowSorter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter%28boolean%29) source code:

```
public void setAutoCreateRowSorter(boolean autoCreateRowSorter) {
    boolean oldValue = this.autoCreateRowSorter;
    this.autoCreateRowSorter = autoCreateRowSorter;
    if (autoCreateRowSorter) {
        setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(getModel()));
    }
    firePropertyChange("autoCreateRowSorter", oldValue,
                       autoCreateRowSorter);
}
```

So, you have two options:

- Keep a reference to the row sorter to restore it later, as @nachokk suggested.
- Set a new [TableRowSorter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) instance:

  `table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(table.getModel()));`

#### Edit

> But now the table's rows are not selectable

That's weird, I didn't have any problem with row selection. Here is the code I've used to test my answer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column # 1", "Column # 2"}, 0){
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) { 
                switch(columnIndex) {
                    case 0: return String.class;
                    case 1: return Integer.class;
                        default: return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
                }
            }            
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"Property # " + i, Integer.valueOf(i)});            
        }

        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton("Disable", true);
        toggleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JToggleButton toggleButton = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();

                String text = toggleButton.isSelected() ? "Disable" : "Enable";
                TableRowSorter sorter = toggleButton.isSelected() ? new TableRowSorter(table.getModel()) : null;

                toggleButton.setText(text);
                table.setRowSorter(sorter);

            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(toggleButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @dic19, it helps me a lot. But now the table's rows are not selectable

Comment: You're welcome! Please see my edit. That's weird, because table sorter shouldn't interfere with row selection at all. Maybe you can post your code @suti